# ghostscript - where can i find gsprint32.exe / gsprint64.exe file in the latest version downloads?

Tags: ghostscript

I see our source code have these files gsprint32.exe / gsprint64.exe when we integrated Ghostscript into our application.

But as part of upgrading to newer version i can find gswin32.exe files but not gsprint32.exe in version 9.25..

Can anyone answer who know about this?

Answer (score 0):

gsprint is not, and never was, part of Ghostscript. Its part of the GSView application which was supplied by Ghostgum Pty.

FWIW I've never known there to be gsprint32 and gsprint64 executable, they've always been just gsprint.exe and stored in the relevant Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview or Program Files (x86)\ghostgum\gsview folder.

The current version of Ghostscript is 9.50